# When an edit is rejected because a conflict with another edit, show the difference between the previous revision, not the last revision

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list

On *Drupal Answers*, I was editing https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83544/create-a-slideshow. After I edited the question, I noticed there was a pending suggested edit; I looked to see if there could be any changes I missed, and that I could incorporate in my edit. Looking at [the suggested edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18526), though, I found it was showing the differences between my edit and the suggested edits, not between the original text and the suggested edit.

[image: screenshot]

The original text in fact is the following.

```
I want to have slideshow of a my custom content type **slideshow** .
my goal is something like below picture
![enter image description here][1]

which module I should use ?
I test views slideshow module but I didn't found settings for slider indicator ( tiny circles in picture) . 

**appreciate good and complete guide to create something like this.**
```

My edit is the following one.

```
I want to have a slideshow of a my custom content type (slideshow). My goal is getting something like the below picture.

![screenshot][1]

Which module should I use?

I testes the [Views Slideshow][2] module, but I didn't find any settings for the slider indicator (those tiny circles on the bottom right corner in the screenshot). 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaBm8.jpg
  [2]: https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow
```

The suggested edit changes the previous revision of the post, and the shown difference should be between the suggested edit and the previous revision.